# Prove that $r_{0,n}$ and $r_{1,n}$ are convex on $(-\infty,0)$.

Tags: convex-analysis, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, truncation-error

Prove that the following two functions are convex on $(-\infty,0)$:
\begin{align}
 r_{0,n}(x)&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{(n+i)!} &
 r_{1,n}(x)&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^i}{(n+i)!} & n = 0,1,\ldots 
\end{align}
The cases $r_{0,0}=\exp(x)$ and $r_{1,0}=\exp(x)-1$ are standard, i.e., I would appreciate help for cases where $n>0$. I tried to prove this by induction, without any success.

Comment: Note that n is fixed in the definition of your functions. What happens if you multiply and divide by x to the power of n for each different n?

Comment: I am aware that $r_{0,n}=\frac{1}{x^n}\left[\exp(x)-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{x^i}{i!}\right]$ (and a similar relation for $r_{1,n}$). Unfortunately, cannot see any convexity from this rewriting.

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but isn't each term of the summation convex?

Comment: @MichaelGrant: no, $x^i$ is not convex for odd $i>1$ on $(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: Ah of course, I’m accustomed to looking at the non-negative interval.